# how to show a modal popup whose body is on a different page in angular

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular5

I need to show a modal popup on a different page whose body is on app.component.html.

**App.Component.html:**

```
  <ng-template #template>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right"
                aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is a modal.
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

**App.component.ts:**

```
   import { TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
   public openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
        debugger;
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template); // {3}
      }
```

**Another.component.html:**

```
 <input type="button" class="btn" (click)="openModal(template)" value="open popup" />
```

**Another.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
 export class ABC implements OnInit {
  template: TemplateRef<any>;
  public openModal(template) {
    debugger;  // getting null as template
    this.appComponent.openModal(template);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular components are intended to be isolated from one another, so creating this kind of direct dependency between components is not possible - you have to inject dependencies.

So, one thing you could do is try to 'inject' the template into another.component. This might work (not tested the code):

App.component.html:

```
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right"
            aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is a modal.
  </div>
</ng-template>
<another-component [template]="myModal"></another-component>
```

App.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('template') myModal; // get your template reference in the component
```

Another.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input template: any; // or perhaps of type TemplateRef<any>;

  public openModal() {
    debugger;
    this.appComponent.openModal(this.template);
  }
 }
```

I am not entirely sure that will work, but worth a try.

However, maybe a better option is when the button is clicked in the child to open the model, you fire an event which app.component then catches, and it opens the modal. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941353/how-to-access-template-reference-variables-from-parent-in-a-child) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677139/angular-4-show-popup-onclick-by-other-component?rq=1).